# How to center without the <center> tag using CSS?

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have some code that uses the center tag to center two buttons on the screen:

```
<center>
    <input type="button" onclick="parent.window.close();" value="Close Window" id="Button1" name="Button1" />
    <% 
       if (Session["MyRoleName"].ToString().ToUpper() == "SUPERMANADMIN")
       {
    %>
    <input type="button" onclick="if (confirm('ARE YOU SURE?  This cannot be undone except by IT at great cost!')) { PurgeCourse(); }" value="Purge Course Comments" id="Button2" name="Button2" />
    <%  } %>
</center>
```

Since the center tag is deprecated, I thought I'd try replacing it with a `<div>` tag, and setting the margin to margin: 0 auto.  This did not center the buttons on the screen.

My question is, how can I center these two buttons on the screen, horizontally, without using the `<center>` tag?

Comment: `margin: auto;` will only center block-type elements. Buttons are normally, by default, inline elements. So either you center them with `text-align: center;`, either you give them `display: block;` along with `margin: auto;`. You can also simply wrap them in an element other than <center> - say, <div> - and center the contents of that div. Also, if you're going to update your code and remove deprecated stuff, things like `onclick=` inside the HTML would be best gone.

Comment: Oh, with the edit, I get it now. Setting a <div> to `margin: auto;` will center the <div> itself, not its contents. And since a <div> by default takes the whole width, well, you won't see the difference. You need to place your centering CSS (whichever you choose) on the buttons, not their container.

Comment: Thanks, Ariane!  I appreciate your insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using css to do this, for sample:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <input type="button" onclick="parent.window.close();" value="Close Window" id="Button1" name="Button1" />
    <% if (Session["MyRoleName"].ToString().ToUpper() == "SUPERMANADMIN") { %>
    <input type="button" onclick="if (confirm('ARE YOU SURE?  This cannot be undone except by IT at great cost!')) { PurgeCourse(); }" value="Purge Course Comments" id="Button2" name="Button2" />
    <%  } %>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!  As soon as timer is up, I'll choose this as the answer.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Centering something using `margin: 0 auto` only works on block-level elements that have a set width (otherwise they'd span the full width of their parent element).

`text-align: center` is fine if you're only trying to center the text *within* an element.

You can find full documentations on CSS text properties here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html